# Ability to set JavaScript breakpoints in browser pointed at local environment

Tags: javascript, breakpoints, request-headers, response-headers

Unfortunately, while JavaScript breakpoints can be set in production, they cannot be set in local. In local, on refresh, JavaScript execution proceeds unimpeded, as if no breakpoint had ever been set. (This has been tested in Chrome, Safari and FF on Mac OS X.)

The current local environment differs in the headers for JavaScript files.

The headers are pasted, below. Is there any difference in the headers being set, which would cause this undesirable behavior in local.

Thanks!

## Production

```
General
Remote Address:23.235.33.207:80
Request URL:http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/example/js/header.top.min.js?ver=1427752599
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Age:149381
Cache-Control:max-age=31536000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:56250
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Wed, 01 Apr 2015 15:28:14 GMT
ETag:"2a5ce-5128893ad1780-gzip"
Last-Modified:Mon, 30 Mar 2015 21:58:06 GMT
Server:Apache
Varnish-X-Cache:HIT
Varnish-X-Cache-Hits:4259
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Cache:HIT
X-Cache-Hits:4259
X-Served-By:cache-jfk1021-JFK
X-Timer:S1427902094.409391,VS0,VE0

Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.104 Safari/537.36

Query String Parameters
ver:1427752599
```

## Local

```
General
Remote Address:192.168.33.28:80
Request URL:http://example.local/wp-content/themes/example/js/header.top.min.js?ver=1427902154
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:173487
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Wed, 01 Apr 2015 15:29:16 GMT
ETag:"2a5af-51294e60377c0"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Tue, 31 Mar 2015 12:40:07 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.6.7

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1427902096929r0.009481394430622458; cn_adsqt=%7B%22count%22%3A1%2C%22expire%22%3A1427984897264%7D; cn_adcap=%7B%22count%22%3A1%2C%22expire%22%3A1427902697265%7D; mbox=session#1427902097343-248716#1427903958|PC#1427902097343-248716.25_59#1435678098; original_referrer=; PHPSESSID=h31joi3efmcp09mgj2t2988jl6; s_pers=%20s_campaign%3D%7C1427903898400%3B%20s_vnum_m%3D1430452800405%2526vn%253D1%7C1430452800405%3B%20sinvisit_m%3Dtrue%7C1427903898405%3B%20s_nr%3D1427902098411%7C1430494098411%3B%20s_eVar10%3D%7C1427903898416%3B%20s_depth%3D1%7C1427903898418%3B%20gpv_p5%3Dhomepage%7C1427903898424%3B; s_sess=%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B; cookies.js_domain_test=1; _parsely_session={%22sid%22:1%2C%22surl%22:%22http://example.local/%22%2C%22sref%22:%22%22%2C%22sts%22:1427902099180%2C%22slts%22:0}; _parsely_visitor={%22id%22:%226c45a1ff-1b3b-4b17-97bd-79418e00d7c3%22%2C%22session_count%22:1%2C%22last_session_ts%22:1427902099180}; __gads=ID=bb7813438602a520:T=1427902100:S=ALNI_MYtP9UgANEBxufSca4E_ceSJBvFkg; optimizelySegments=%7B%222494890534%22%3A%22false%22%2C%222501230342%22%3A%22direct%22%2C%222501840319%22%3A%22none%22%2C%222515720226%22%3A%22gc%22%7D; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; optimizelyPendingLogEvents=%5B%22n%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fexample.local%252F%26u%3Doeu1427902096929r0.009481394430622458%26wxhr%3Dtrue%26t%3D1427902156634%26f%3D2725330192%26g%3D%22%5D
Host:example.local
Referer:http://example.local/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.104 Safari/537.36

Query String Parameters
ver:1427902154
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the version number change with each request/build in your local?

> header.top.min.js?ver=1427902154

If it does, your browser will look at it as a different file and you will lose your breakpoints. This is by design, as the reason it is included in your code is to break your cache.

Try setting the version to a constant in dev, or removing it all together.

Comment: Nice @Remento! An obvious oversight on my part, but I do really appreciate you pointing that out. A +50 bounty for you, good sir!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to force a breakpoint and you're in local, you can always drop a debugger statement inside the JavaScript file:

```
// code that does something
if (runningLocally) {
debugger;
}
// code that does something
```

You'll have to delete those lines when you push to production, or at least build some logic to run the line only when you're running locally. But this way you can ensure execution will halt at that breakpoint whenever you have dev tools open.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: Yep, debugger statements are another option. Although I am using sourcemaps, somewhere along the way, debugger statements are being stripped out, possibly by either the requirejs or uglify Grunt tasks. That is another issue I am investigating. But I didn't want to make the original question too complicated, with those details, too. Either way, I would like to get both debugger statements and browser breakpoints working.

Comment: If you use a UglifyJS to minify your code it will remove `debugger` statements by default.

Comment: It occurs to me that although I have `drop_debugger: false` in my uglify task, I don't have/am not aware of a way to set that same flag in the uglify2 concatenation that is being run as part of the requirejs task. Hm.

Comment: Up-voting this answer, as well, because having all options available for debugging code only increases developer fun/satisfaction.